# Twilio : Retrieve a list of Room by UniqueName not working

Tags: php, twilio

https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource?code-sample=code-retrieve-a-list-of-rooms-by-uniquename&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x

Based on the documentation above, I tried listing the detail of the room in twilio using uniqueName. My code looks simply like this

```
$twilio = new Client(config('services.twilio.sid'), config('services.twilio.token'));
$rooms = $twilio->video->v1->rooms->read(["uniqueName" => "3302"], 20);
dd($rooms);
```

So, when I try to dd(); the $rooms, it's showing an empty array. 
[image]

But when I go to my twilio room log, there is a list of the room

[image]

Is there something that I am missing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, fixed it. I used the wrong twilio key/secret. I have multiple twilio accounts.